# Error with setting data to subkey at Registry

Tags: delphi, registry

I am trying to write new key i.e Mode and assign a a value to it, my system is 32 bit and code is as follows. I am getting an error with the following code as *failed to set data for Mode* I have tried with all rectification by setting different parameters to reg.Access but no success. I always have to keep reg.Access to KEY_READ as with KEY_WRITE it will not open subkey at reg.OpenKey method.

```
  reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ);
  reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;

  if (not reg.KeyExists('\Software\MyApp\appname\')) then
  begin
      MessageDlg('Key not found! Created now.', mtInformation, mbOKCancel, 0);
  end;

  reg.Access:= KEY_READ;
  openResult := reg.OpenKey('\Software\MyApp\appname\',True);
      if not openResult = True then
      begin
          MessageDlg('Unable to create key! Exiting.', mtError, mbOKCancel, 0);
          Exit();
      end;


      if not reg.KeyExists('Mode') then
      begin
        reg.WriteString('Mode','trial');
      end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`KEY_READ` gives you read access. But that's not enough for you. You pass `True` to the `CanCreate` argument of `OpenKey` and so need the `KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY` access flag. And then you attempt to write a value, which requires the `KEY_WRITE` access flag.

Your problem is presumably that your process executes as a user without sufficient rights. You will need to make sure that your program runs with sufficient rights. Usually this means running it as administrator. Use the application manifest to enforce that, or the `runas` verb, whichever method is most appropriate for your application.